# php cUrl Error init error

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am trying to use curl and I thought this was built in to PHP for a long time.

But I am getting the following error  Call to undefined function curl_init()

I copied this code from a ajax tutorial, could anyone point me in the right direction please.

```
 $url = $_POST['url'];
 unset($_POST['url']);
 $fields_string = "";
 //url-ify the data for the POST
 foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
     $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
 }
 $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();
 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
 //execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 //close connection
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: Enable curl in your php.ini, or search for enable curl on here or google. You also might have to install it.

Comment: Hi version 5.3.8, got it working now but it thinks one of the parameters is missing, but when I manually copy into the URL all works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `file_get_contents` instead of `cURL` ?

```
$url = (isset($_POST['url']) && is_string($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : die('url parameter required.');
unset($_POST['url']);
$data = http_build_query($_POST, '', '&');
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => implode("\r\n", array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
        )),
        'content' => $data,
    ),
)));
```

Comment: thanks, just trying file_get_contents doesn't return anything my client jquery opens a blank alert box.